# plugging usb device to different port may require driver reinstall - how to prevent?

Tags: windows, usb, drivers

some devices (e.g usb printers), require that the driver is installed again if/when i plug their usb cable to a different port.

i'm on windows xp sp3.

this has problematic implications, e.g.

- a usb drive might change its drive-letter
- a printer driver might create a new entry in the printers list
- user intervension might be required where users aren't/shouldn't/can't interact with system settings.

is there a way to prevent a "by-port" device identification?

(my specific printer has just now a firmware update for that, but the question is relevant to other devices as well)

Answer (score 1):

Not really. This is why when I have to install say a usb printer or a usb camera for someone I simply plug it into each usb port and install the drivers.

Comment: yes, but that causes a major problems e.g. with printers, e.g. default printer which is using the "worng" usb port, etc.